# How can I use different language via coding in android studio?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an app which gives a feature to choose the language in which only the reports will be generated. Is there any way in which I can achieve this.  I don't want to use the localization feature because it will then translate my whole app.

Sorry If I am not clear enough.
In my app I have a feature through which certain reports (I have used fragments as there are 5+ pages) are generated.
Mainactivity has an option to set the language for reports. 
Now when the language is selected only the reports need to be translated to the selected language.

I tried the strings.xml approach but then it translates the entire app which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to prevent a string from being translated. Do this, declare the string in the strings.xml file and then set translatable to "false" for that particular string.